TailwindCSS not implementing properly on deployment
I have recently started a project using the npm create vite@latest my-project -- -- template react as stated in the Vite Guide. So far I have been doing well with the project in development running in localhost. However, when I now tried to deploy it in Vercel, some of the TailwindCSS styles are not being implemented as well as some images.
For example: src\assets\css\login.css
#app-container {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;

  .content {
    @apply flex items-center justify-center;
    grid-column: auto;
    grid-row: auto;
    background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/techno-blue-hexagonal-wave.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    .login-container {
        @apply justify-center w-full px-4;
        
        .col {
            @apply rounded-md py-4;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

            .logo {
                @apply mt-3 mb-4 mx-auto w-2/3;
            }

            .form-group {
                @apply px-4 mx-auto;

                .form-label {
                    @apply text-text font-mono text-sm;
                }
    
                .form-control {
                    @apply font-mono;
                }
            }

            .btn-submit {
                @apply text-text font-bold mx-auto mt-8 block px-10;
                background-color: #0d6efd;
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .login-container {
        .form-group {
            @apply px-0;
            width: 90%;
        }
    }
}

The one with the @apply Tailwind styles is not being implemented when I deployed it in Vercel. As well as the background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/techno-blue-hexagonal-wave.jpg'); where the image is located in the same assets folder except in /assets/images. Here are the configurations I have with TailwindCSS and PostCSS as I followed in the TailwindCSS Guide.
tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: '#2a2a2a',
      'primary-rgb': '42, 42, 42',
      secondary: '#39ff14',
      'secondary-rgb': '57, 255, 20',
      tertiary: '#2ed610',
      'tertiary-rgb': '46, 214, 16',
      accent: '#ff0000',
      'accent-rgb': '255, 0, 0',
      background: '#1e1e1e',
      'background-rgb': '30, 30, 30',
      text: '#f5f5f5',
      'text-rgb': '245, 245, 245',
      danger: '#dc3545'
    },
    fontFamily: {
      serif: ['EB Garamond', 'serif'],
      sans: ['Neuton', 'sans-serif'],
      mono: ['Courier Prime', 'monospace'],
      cursive: ['Dancing Script', 'cursive'],
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

postcss.config.js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? { cssnano: {} } : {}),
  },
};

package.json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Something.",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git-repo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",
    "@lordicon/react": "^1.10.0",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "lottie-web": "^5.12.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.9.0",
    "react-svg": "^16.1.34",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
    "cssnano": "^7.0.6",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.47",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
    "vite": "^5.4.8"
  }
}

Any ideas on where I might have gone wrong or if I'm missing something? My css are in the src\assets\css\ folder and the images I have used are in the src\assets\images\ folder. I hope someone could help.

Please check build script and where it is deploy the files and be sure that same structure should be in there

At the top of your CSS file, you need to import Tailwind's directives.
/* login.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* The rest of your CSS code */

Tailwind Docs (Step 4) says:

Add the Tailwind directives to your CSS
Add the @tailwind directives for each of Tailwind’s layers to your
main CSS file.


Yes I do have this added in the main css file which is in the /src/index.css. I'm new to tailwind, do you mean that I need to include the Tailwind directives to each css files that is in the /src/assets/css/?

@LourdNathanielGonzalez Yes. The Tailwind directives needs to be at the top of each CSS file in which you want to use Tailwind because login.css doesn't "grab" the directives you placed in main.css

Okay I have added the directives to each of my css files as you instructed and pushed it in my git repo, however in Vercel, though no errors are showing, the styles are still not working and not implementing. The @apply styles and the images as like in the background-image: url('../images/backgrounds/techno-blue-hexagonal-wave.jpg'); in the login.css. I don't know if it has something to do with the build command or the configurations of my postcss and tailwindcss configs.

Everything is normal and working in localhost when I run the npm run dev command in terminal and opened it in browser. It is exactly as I'm hoping it would, but the issue is when it is deployed in Vercel. I don't know what configuration I'm missing.

Okay good news is I found a work-around with the issue in the images when loading by css. I just moved the images folder to the /public folder that way it can be accessed directly. But the issue with using the @apply styling with Tailwind still persists. Any ideas how to fix this? There is no issue when running it locally through npm run dev and opening it in browser http://localhost:port. But when I deploy it in Vercel or tried to npm run build then npm run preview and open the build preview on browser, the @apply styles are not being implemented.
